# Type of singularity at $z=0$ in $(e^z)/(z+ \sin(z))$

Tags: complex-analysis, singularity

I want to know as to  whether a singularity can be removable as well as a pole. If we take the complex function $f(z)= (e^z)/(z+ \sin(z))$ and consider the singularity at $z=0$ then on the face of it, it looks like a simple pole as the denominator has a simple zero at $z=0$. 
Now to evaluate the residue we will have to consider the limit $(ze^z/(z+ \sin(z))$ as $z$ tends to $0$. To compute this limit we will have to define $\sin(z)/z$ as $z$ tends to $0$ as $1$. The limit comes out to be $1/2$. Am I being correct in calling this singularity a pole. My confusion arises
from the aforementioned definition of $\sin(z)/z$ as $z$ tends to $0$ which is done in case of removable singularities.

Comment: $sin(z) = z - \frac{z^{3}}{3!}+\frac{z^{5}}{5!}-..., z\in\mathbb{C}$, therefore $\frac{sin(z)}{z} = 1- \frac{z^{2}}{3!}+\frac{z^{4}}{5!}-...,$. So $\frac{sin(z)}{z}$ can be viewed as an analytic function with value $1$ at $z=0$.

Comment: @Sander Does that make the singularity at $z=0$ a simple pole?

Comment: If $zf(z)$ is analytic at $z = 0$, then it is a simple pole. But $zf(z) = \frac{e^{z}}{1 + \frac{sin(z)}{z}}$, $e^{z}$ and $1+\frac{sin(z)}{z}$ are analytic at $z=0$ and $1+\frac{sin(z)}{z}$ is nonzero at $z=0$. Therefore, $zf(z)$ is analytic at $z=0$ and it is a simple pole.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds to me as if you’re slightly confused about limits. In particular, the sentence “To compute this limit we will have to define $\sin(z)/z$ as $z$ tends to $0$ as $1$” makes no sense. No definition is required here (beyond the general definition of the term “limit”); the limit of $\frac{\sin z}z$ for $z\to0$ is $1$. The expression $\frac{\sin z}z$ is undefined at $z=0$. You can define it to be $1$ there if you like, but that’s not necessary in order to find that its limit for $z\to0$ is $1$.

Everything else that you wrote is correct. The denominator has a simple zero at $z=0$, and thus the function has a simple pole there, and the residue at this pole is $\frac12$, as you correctly determined by finding the limit of $zf(z)$.